# How to check if many-to-many related field contain all of given values

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I have two django models with ManyToMany relationship:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)


class Bookmark(models.Model):
    # ....
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I would like to write a `filter_backends` that given a list of tag names returns only those bookmarks that have assigned all of those tags (and possibly more of them).

Example:

**Given** `bookmark_a` with `tags==['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`
**And** `bookmark_b` with `tags==['foo', 'baz']`
**Then** calling url `.../bookmarks/?tags=foo,bar` will return only `bookmark_a`